# Writing multiple files as output when webscraping - python bs4

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

to preface - I am quite new to python and my HTML skills are kindergarten level.

So I am trying to save the quotes from [this website](http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm) which has many links in it for each member of the US Election candidates.

I have managed to get the actual code to extract the quotes (with the help of soem stackoverflow users), but am lost on how to write these quotes in to separate text files for each candidate.

For example, the first page, with all of Justin Amash's quotes should be written to a file: JustinAmash.txt.
The second page, with all of Michael Bennet's quotes should be written to MichaelBennet.txt (or something in that form). and so on.. Is there a way to do this?

For reference, to scrape the pages, the following code works:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen as uReq, HTTPError 
#Import HTTPError in order to avoid the links with no content/resource of interest
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup_
import re
#define url of interest
my_url = 'http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm'


def make_soup(url):
    # set up known browser user agent for the request to bypass HTMLError
    req=Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    #opening up connection, grabbing the page
    uClient = uReq(req)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    #html is jumbled at the moment, so call html using soup function
    soup = soup_(page_html, "lxml") 
    return soup

# Test: print title of page
#soup.title

soup = make_soup(my_url)
tags = soup.findAll("a" , href=re.compile("javascript:pop\("))
#print(tags)

# open a text file and write it if it doesn't exist
file1 = open("Quotefile.txt","w")

# get list of all URLS
for links in tags:
    link = links.get('href')
    if "java" in link: 
        print("http://archive.ontheissues.org" + link[18:len(link)-3])
        main_url = "http://archive.ontheissues.org" + link[18:len(link)-3] 
        try:
            sub_soup = make_soup(main_url)
            content_collexn = sub_soup.body.contents #Splitting up the page into contents for iterative access 
            #text_data = [] #This list can be used to store data related to every person
            for item in content_collexn:
                #Accept an item if it belongs to the following classes
                if(type(item) == str):
                    print(item.get_text())
                elif(item.name == "h3"):
                    #Note that over here, every h3 tagged title has a string following it
                    print(item.get_text())   
                    #Hence, grab that string too
                    print(item.next_sibling) 
                elif(item.name in ["p", "ul", "ol"]):
                    print(item.get_text())

        except HTTPError: #Takes care of missing pages and related HTTP exception
            print("[INFO] Resource not found. Skipping to next link.")

        #print(text_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store that text data into the list you had started with `text_data`. Join all those items and then write to file:

So something like:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen as uReq, HTTPError 
#Import HTTPError in order to avoid the links with no content/resource of interest
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup_
import re
#define url of interest
my_url = 'http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm'


def make_soup(url):
    # set up known browser user agent for the request to bypass HTMLError
    req=Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    #opening up connection, grabbing the page
    uClient = uReq(req)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    #html is jumbled at the moment, so call html using soup function
    soup = soup_(page_html, "lxml") 
    return soup

# Test: print title of page
#soup.title

soup = make_soup(my_url)
tags = soup.findAll("a" , href=re.compile("javascript:pop\("))
#print(tags)

# open a text file and write it if it doesn't exist
#file1 = open("Quotefile.txt","w")

# get list of all URLS
candidates = []
for links in tags:

    link = links.get('href')
    if "java" in link: 
        #print("http://archive.ontheissues.org" + link[18:len(link)-3])
        main_url = "http://archive.ontheissues.org" + link[18:len(link)-3]
        candidate = link.split('/')[-1].split('_Free_Trade')[0]

        if candidate in candidates:
            continue
        else:
            candidates.append(candidate)

        try:
            sub_soup = make_soup(main_url)
            content_collexn = sub_soup.body.contents #Splitting up the page into contents for iterative access 
            text_data = [] #This list can be used to store data related to every person
            for item in content_collexn:
                #Accept an item if it belongs to the following classes
                if(type(item) == str):
                    #print(item.get_text())
                    text_data.append(item.get_text())
                elif(item.name == "h3"):
                    #Note that over here, every h3 tagged title has a string following it
                    #print(item.get_text()) 
                    text_data.append(item.get_text())
                    #Hence, grab that string too
                    #print(item.next_sibling) 
                    text_data.append(item.next_sibling)
                elif(item.name in ["p", "ul", "ol"]):
                    #print(item.get_text())
                    text_data.append(item.get_text())

        except HTTPError: #Takes care of missing pages and related HTTP exception
            print("[INFO] Resource not found. Skipping to next link.")
            candidates.remove(candidate)
            continue

        text_data = '\n'.join(text_data)
        with open("C:/%s.txt" %(candidate), "w") as text_file:
            text_file.write(text_data)
        print('Aquired: %s' %(candidate))
```